# Using R, variadically checking if `exists`

Tags: r, variadic-functions, variadic

I would like to wrap `R::base` function `exists` into a wrapper function to make it more C-based and variadic in nature.

```
### current examples of `exists` usage

if(!exists(".humanVerse")) { initMemory(); }

#############################

if(!exists("path", .GlobalEnv$.humanVerse) || purge.memory)
        {  
        ### do something here
        }

#############################

if(exists(save.key, .GlobalEnv$.humanVerse[["colors"]][["dataframes"]]))
            {
            return( .GlobalEnv$.humanVerse[["colors"]][["dataframes"]][[save.key]] );
            }
```

The above examples work fine, in the order applied.  But if I wanted to write a function to capture or trap the non-existent key, it will cause a problem.

```
exists("not.created");
```

whereas

```
checkExists = function(x)
    {
    exists(x);  
    }

checkExists(not.created);
```

throws an object not found error.  Of course, I recognize that the "string" form of "not.created" is different than a variadic form.

I am looking for a way for the `checkExists` function to work.

The `x` in `exists` looks for a name, a character vector.  What if I want to `checkExists` on an object, not a character?  That is the essence of the variadic question.

Maybe I am merely asking how to capture the character name of the object?  I don't know.  `R::base` logic contorts my logic from time to time.

Comment: what if you do `x<-"not.created"` then `checkExists(x)`, what exactly should it check for? `x` or `not.created`? I'm also not sure I understand what you mean by "variadic". Normally that means you can pass any number of arguments to a function but in each of these cases you seem to be passing just one.

Comment: Yes, how do I cast a potential object `not.created` into a character `"not.created"` so that could occur?

Comment: What are you answering "yes" to? I'm confused. Do you want your function only to take symbol names and never variables? So in the case of `varname <- "not.created"; exists(varname)`, what should it be testing?

Comment: fun2 <- function (var_pass) { deparse(substitute(var_pass)) }

Comment: `dir.exists` and `file.exists` behave very different from `exists` ... I get contorted and confused.